# how can i put h2 tags into grid's right above my paragraphs without them taking up an entire grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I am working on a freecodecamp project. When i put heading tags above a paragraph, the heading doesn't stay above it, it takes up its own grid and shoots off into placement. I can do this correctly using grid areas, but i want to do it this way if possible. Should i wrap each h2 and paragraph in another div? For example  and still use the main container for grid?

```css
    .container {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 1em;
    background: #fff;}
```

```html
  <body>
    <div class='container'>
    <h2>Some title</h2>
    <p>some test goes here</p>
    </div>
    </body>
```

I would like the headings to placed over my paragraphs as they should.

Answer (score 0):

I would place both the elements in a div and make another parent element with the grid class.

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}

.master-grid {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #aabeff;
}

.container {
  background-color: #4772ff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='master-grid'>
    <div class='container'>
      <h2>Title 1</h2>
      <p>some text goes here</p>
    </div>
    <div class='container'>
      <h2>Title 2</h2>
      <p>some text goes here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```